# Call to a member function define() on null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting error: `Call to a member function define() on null`

Here is my code:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Comment: where do you use this code?

Comment: The error tells, that `$factory === null`. Hence, no `define()` method can be called on it. We need to know where `$factory` is defined or see the entire code of your class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got the answer i just needed to include the html  form aliases and packages..

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you did exactly to help other users with the same problem?

Comment: in laravel to use html Form Class , we need to first download some dependencies and we need to some code in our app.php file .

Comment: @RupeshChaudhari you shouldn't just say that you found the answer. please share the answer.